# Android with Asmack - How do I fetch current presence information when I connect to XMPP?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I have an asmack based client, I connect and authenticate, then I fetch a roster, to which I attach a listener and I set myself available.

The listener correctly picks up any changes to presence made after I connect, however I can't find a way of getting the current state of all the entries on my roster.

I tried sending a `Presence.Type.subscribe` packet, I tried using `Roster#reload()` and I've tried the following:

```
for (RosterEntry entry : mRoster.getEntries()) {
   Presence presence = mRoster.getPresence( entry.getUser() );
   ...
}
```

(If  I log the presence object above, they all show as 'unavailable')

I've also tried `mRoster.getPresence(handle)` inside `entriesUpdated` when I get the callback from `Roster#reload` and separately when looping over `Roster#getEntries`, I get valid user id's but the presence mode is null and type is unavailable for every entry

Is there a way I can prompt the server to send me the current remote information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue, it appears part of the example I followed to set up my configuration was incorrect.

Including the following setting in your `ConnectionConfiguration` will cause the issue:

```
config.setSendPresence(false);
```

After I removed this, initial presences were updated correctly

Comment: Where is the example from?

Comment: I looked at a few, but I believe it was from the source code for Yaxim  http://yaxim.org/ not official docs. If you don't mind answering - is there a way to get these intial updates and not send presence initially as I don't want to show available and then go back to whatever state I saved, I want to only send the saved state

Comment: I think that it should/must be possible, but on top of my head I can't tell you the exact procedure.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I tried manually sending a packet once I connect - it's enough to trigger us receiving others new updates but not to get initial states

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Roster.getEntries()
```

?

Comment: I looped through them and did getPresence and had the same issue I mentioned above under 'one more note', do you know why?

Comment: Where is there a issue? I only see a log line that doesn't seem to be related to Smack's Roster at all.

Comment: The line does appear unrelated, I think it is a side affect from something else I am doing. The issue is, I'm doing what's shown in the block of code above but the presence object has mode null, type unavailable for every entry

Comment: I figured it out, mistake in configuration, thanks for your help

Comment: @Flow : Please Guide me through this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372589/create-message-while-sending-image-through-asmack